# React to click on the ...-button

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

By default there is a ... `Button` (aka. the menu overflow `Button`) in the top right corner of an Android `ActionBar`.
This `Button` opens the options menu overflow, from which the user can choose different items.

Is it possible to directly react to a press on the ... `Button`?

What I want to achieve is that **no menu pops up**. Instead the behavior I want is to open a new `Activity`. Like a settings-activity.

Comment: Your question is not that's clear.

Comment: In what way? Which information is missing in your opinion?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? The question seems legit to me and I completely understand what he wants.

Comment: I also don't agree with all of those downvotes. I've made an edit to try to help with that.

Comment: Seriously, people are still downvoting this? The question is legit, and now it's easy to read. And NO ONE is giving a good reason on the comments whatsoever for the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you think:

**edit2:**

one more thing you have to change:

```
res-> menu-> your_menu_xml

<item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit_pass"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
```

**android:showAsAction="always"**

```
        android:title="@string/action_edit_pass"/>
```

this will chane the "..." to the value you write in it.

Comment: This is what I have right now. I want to skip the options menu and directly open another activity.

Comment: but you want a button... this is a button work like any other button in the activity xml, it will open an another activity... but in the action bar you have to implement as settings button

Comment: hi, is this edited answer acceptable for you? Becasue i think this is what you thought about when you wrote your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to use a `Toolbar` instead of the default `ActionBar`. That way, you'll be able to simple add an Overflow `Button` or `ImageButton` (...) to the right of the `Toolbar` and you could simply use a `onClickListener()`.

An example:

First, declare your `Toolbar` xml.

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="ANY_HEX_COLOR"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt_overflow"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_more" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Later, hide the default `ActionBar` by setting a `NoActionBar` theme on your `style.xml`. Something like:

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now, add your `Toolbar` on your `Activity` xml file.

**my_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl_root"
    tools:context="com.testapp.ToolBarActivity">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.testapp.ToolBarActivity">



        <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, on your `Activity`, make it inherit from `ActionBarActivity`. And set your listener.

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class ToolBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tool_bar);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);

        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt_overflow);

        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity();
            }
        });

        toolbar.setTitle("Test");
    }

    private void startActivity() {
        Intent it = new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class);

        startActivity(it);
    }
}
```

**P.S.:** Don't forget to add the support lib on your gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

And if you want that `Toolbar` to behave like an ordinary `ActionBar`, just add this line to your `onCreate()`:

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```